# Can I be a Conjurer Specialist and get Evoker Variant (UA)?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, archetype

Or I need to be evocation specialist to get the evoker variant.

I want to be conjurer Specialist but take the Energy Affinity and Energy Substitution. Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, no. The variant specialists must be specialists in the given school first, before those abilities become options.

Energy substitution is available as [a metamagic feat by the same name](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/divine/divineAbilitiesFeats.htm#energySubstitution), but you have to choose what type of energy when you take the feat. You could take it multiple times to get all the types of energy, but that’s hugely wasteful, and in any event you would still have to prepare each spell with one of them, so it’s still not as flexible as the evoker’s version. Still, if you want to *specialize* in a particular type of magic—maybe fire damage for a Searing Spell mailman—it’s plenty good enough for that.

Energy affinity is a relatively small bonus; you can do better by just using an *orange ioun stone*. This would stack with that, but meh. It’s really not that huge a bonus. Note that *Complete Mage* has reserve feats that give a minor at-will ability, and also give +1 to caster level with particular spells—there’s one for each of the types that energy affinity offers. Debatable whether they’re worth a feat, but if you really want that CL they exist.

Comment: idk how to format.  
I decided to be evocaion specialist with energy substitution and energy affinity. Can i still take that wizard variant thing that gives me fighter bonus feat but lose scribe scroll and wizard bonus feat list?

This character that I have in mind is a Frost Mage. So i'm using the Frostburn book to get the Frost Mage prestige class.

level 1 I get snowcasting + improved initiative (if possible with the fighter bonus);
level 3 Frozen Magic;
level 6 i become wizard5/frost mage 1;
  
I was checking which scholls i would use more to determine the specialization.

Comment: @BrunoQuevedoNeves Yes, that variant is separate from the specialist variants and can be combined with them (so long as you still have Scribe Scroll to lose). Talk to your DM about it, though—as with all variant rules, the variant classes and class features require a little more DM input than usual. As for being a frost mage, Conjuration is better than Evocation—you could use *orb of frost* from *Spell Compendium*, or just take Energy Substitution (the feat) for cold, no need for the evoker’s version. But the evoker would work.